# select column in pandas dataframe whose nested list value matches a given value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame like this:

```
>>> MCQ_DATA['q45']
10    [13, 14]
11    [13, 14]
12    [13, 12]
13    [13, 12]
14     [9, 12]
15      [2, 6]
16         [2]
17        [16]
18    [13, 12]
19    [13, 11]
```

So all values for column 'q45' are lists. I want to create a boolean filter for rows that contain 13, like:

```
>>> [MCQ_DATA['q45'] == 13]
10    True
11    True
12    True
13    True
14    False
15    False
16    False
17    False
18    True
19    True
```

Already tried these:

- `[MCQ_DATA['q45'] == 13]` returns false for everything.
- `[MCQ_DATA['q45'].isin([13])]` returns `TypeError`. Also, this looks for values against a list. I want to check a nested list in a dataframe for a value. (from [Use a list of values to select rows from a pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12096252/use-a-list-of-values-to-select-rows-from-a-pandas-dataframe))
- `df.loc[df['q45'] == 13]` returns an empty dataframe, because none of the values are `13`. (From [Select rows from a DataFrame based on values in a column in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071871/select-rows-from-a-dataframe-based-on-values-in-a-column-in-pandas))
- `df['q45'].apply(lambda sublist: 13 in sublist)`finally, this worked. But the source says this is not an efficient way to do it: [Operating on tuples held within Pandas DataFrame column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32872849/operating-on-tuples-held-within-pandas-dataframe-column))

I've after looking on SO for the prerequisite half-hour, if the last way is not the right way, what IS the right way?

Further testing found this also works. I would say it is the best approach. Uses pandas framework and easily readable:

- `df['q45'].dropna().apply({13}.issubset)` -- I'm guessing this is faster if I do that on a large scale, but maybe someone knows. (I needed the `.dropna()` because `nan` gives an error.)

Comment: I've updated the dupe target answer with you in mind.  Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks @piRSquared -- but my question was of the many ways you outline, which is the best way, if you have to run this at scale?

Comment: This is an art and depends on your situation.  I suspect my Numpy approach would be quicker.  If you'd like, I can reopen this question to encourage someone to answer with more explanation.  But I do believe the information you need is in the answers from the dupe target.

Comment: no, your dupe answer was fine. thanks.

Comment: Okay @piRSquared I have another problem. Not exactly this - but I'm getting TypeError (float) issues when applying the `.issubset` method and these are being caused by `nan` in the data (np.nan must be type(float)) -- how can I have it ignore the `nan` parts while applying the filter?

Comment: You could try to dropna then reindex after

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181695/discussion-between-marc-maxson-and-pirsquared).